# Australian Tax Rates for overseas residents?

Tags: income-tax, australia

I am an Australian living in Turkey. My old boss in Australia wants me to do some policy work for him. What's the tax issues if I do it?

Answer (score 1):

[The ATO has information on this](https://www.ato.gov.au/Individuals/International-tax-for-individuals/Going-overseas/Working-overseas/Reporting-your-foreign-employment-income/). However, the tax rates that apply to you will be based on whether you are an Australian resident **for tax purposes**. [The ATO has a tool for assisting with this](http://calculators.ato.gov.au/scripts/axos/axos.asp?CONTEXT=&KBS=residency_leaving.XR4), but you may need to speak to an income tax accountant if the tool is unable to give you an answer.

But, basically:

- If you are not an Australian resident for tax purposes, you will be taxed at [foreign resident rates](https://www.ato.gov.au/Rates/Individual-income-tax-rates/#Foreign_residents)
- If you are, then you will be taxed at the usual [individual income rates](https://www.ato.gov.au/Rates/Individual-income-tax-rates/)

This assumes that you are paid by an Australian employer that is registered in Australia (that is, your old boss in Australia has no Turkish company with which he would pay you)